# How to find the index of the element in a list that first appears in another given list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing, set

```
a = [3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5]
b = [4, 6]
```

The answer should be 1. Because in a, 4 appears first in list b, and it's index is 1.

The question is that is there any fast code in python to achieve this?

PS: Actually a is a random permutation and b is a subset of a, but it's represented as a list.

Comment: So the answer should be the same for `b = [6, 4]`? Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Is `b` always a subset, or could there be values in `b` that are not in `a`?

Comment: So, you basically want `a.index(b[0])`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: see my questions, I don't think so.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters is right.

Answer (score 3):

If `b` is to be seen as a subset (order doesn't matter, all values are present in `a`), then use `min()` with a `map()`:

```
min(map(a.index, b))
```

This returns the lowest index. This is a O(NK) solution (where N is the length of `a`, K that of `b`), but all looping is executed in C code.

Another option is to convert `a` to a set and use `next()` on a loop over `enumerate()`:

```
bset = set(b)
next(i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in bset)
```

This is a O(N) solution, but has higher constant cost (Python bytecode to execute). It heavily depends on the sizes of `a` and `b` which one is going to be faster.

For the small input example in the question, `min(map(...))` wins:

```
In [86]: a = [3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5]
    ...: b = [4, 6]
    ...:

In [87]: %timeit min(map(a.index, b))
    ...:
608 ns ± 64.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [88]: bset = set(b)
    ...:

In [89]: %timeit next(i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v in bset)
    ...:
717 ns ± 30.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line :

```
print("".join([str(index) for item in b for index,item1 in enumerate(a) if item==item1][:1]))
```

output:

```
1
```

> In detail :

```
a = [3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5]
b = [4, 6]

new=[]
for item in b:
    for index,item1 in enumerate(a):
        if item==item1:
            new.append(index)

print("".join([str(x) for x in new[:1]]))
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the *first* index.

Comment: That still doesn't give you the lowest index. If `a = [6, 4]` you'd get the wrong answer.

Comment: And why slice and convert to a string and join? Why not just use `[0]`?

Comment: where is wrong, if a= [6,4] then it giving the answer `5` which is first the index of first element which is `6` , and because OP said that he wanted an answer like `1` so , i just.join it , ;)

Comment: It should not, it should produce `1`, as that's the first matching index. Your code is otherwise a very expensive way of spelling `a.index(b[0])`; if you only want the first result, why loop *at all*?

Answer (score 0):

For little B sample, the set approach is output dependent, execution time grow linearly with index output. Numpy can provide better solution in this case.

```
N=10**6
A=np.unique(np.random.randint(0,N,N))
np.random.shuffle(A)
B=A[:3].copy()
np.random.shuffle(A)

def find(A,B):
    pos=np.in1d(A,B).nonzero()[0]
    return pos[A[pos].argsort()][B.argsort().argsort()].min()


def findset(A,B):
    bset = set(B)
    return  next(i for i, v in enumerate(A) if v in bset)

#In [29]: find(A,B)==findset(A,B)
#Out[29]: True
#In [30]: %timeit findset(A,B)
# 63.5 ms ± 1.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# 
# In [31]: %timeit find(A,B)
# 2.24 ms ± 52.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```