# Determine the position of each element of an array B in another array A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Given two lists:

```
In [518]: A
Out[518]: [3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5]

In [519]: B
Out[519]: [4, 6]
```

Every element in `B` exists in `A`, without exception.

I'd like to retrieve an array of indexes for `B` as seen in A. For example, 4 is present in index 1 in A, and 6 is in position 5 for `B`. My expected output is `[1, 5]` for this scenario.

This is what I did to get the index:

```
In [520]: np.flatnonzero(np.in1d(a, b))
Out[520]: array([1, 5])
```

*Unfortunately*, this won't work in most other cases. For example, if `B = [6, 4]`, my method still outputs `[1, 5]` when it should output `[5, 1]`.

Is there an efficient numpy way to get what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Fairly sure this has come up before? What about duplicates?

Comment: The help for `np.where` gives this exact example: `ix = np.in1d(A.ravel(), B).reshape(A.shape); np.where(ix)`.  Sorry, doesn't match your second criterion.

Comment: @JonClements Might've, couldn't find anything... As for dupes in B, surely any numpy method worth its salt should be able to handle those appropriately, but it wouldn't hurt me either way.

Comment: @p-robot yes, and besides, my `flatnonzero`  method is a little nicer. ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Do you absolutely have to use numpy? If you use default dict and have a list of indices for each value in A, then use that to find out indices for elements in B ...

Comment: @Asterisk Yes, this question was inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862148/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-element-in-a-list-that-first-appears-in-another-giv and a slight modification of Martijn Pieters' answer will give me what I want in python. My question is more out of curiosity for the "how".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ah ha! I knew I'd seen those A and Bs before :p

Comment: So, this is different from your previous one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830838/?

Comment: @Divakar Wow... I definitely don't remember asking that... (100 questions later... :-) )  I think it _might_ be a dupe, but I can't remember the context, and MaxU's solution is sufficiently different from anything else to leave it open. I leave the decision to you.

Comment: So, if there are duplicates in `A`, it should get all those indices and not just the first one?

Comment: @Divakar I think it'd be simpler (less headache) to get just the first, and that's fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [71]: a
Out[71]: array([3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6, 5, 6, 4])

In [72]: b
Out[72]: array([4, 6])

In [73]: np.where(a==b[:,None])[1]
Out[73]: array([1, 8, 5, 7], dtype=int64)

In [74]: b = np.array([6, 4])

In [75]: np.where(a==b[:,None])[1]
Out[75]: array([5, 7, 1, 8], dtype=int64)
```

**UPDATE:** if you need only indices of **first** occurances (in case there are duplicates in `A` array), then use [this solution from @Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862256/determine-the-position-of-each-element-of-an-array-b-in-another-array-a/46862663?noredirect=1#comment80673054_46862663), which will be faster:

```
In [84]: (a==b[:,None]).argmax(1)
Out[84]: array([5, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm looking for `[1, 5]` in the first instance and `[5, 1]` in the second. Your answer seems to be getting there but not quite there :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i've changed your `a` array ;-)

Comment: Oh my, I didn't realise. Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks so much!

Comment: I guess you would need `(a==b[:,None]).argmax(1)` if [just the first instance is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862256/determine-the-position-of-each-element-of-an-array-b-in-another-array-a#comment80673034_46862256).

Comment: @Divakar, yeah, with [that additional condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862256/determine-the-position-of-each-element-of-an-array-b-in-another-array-a#comment80673034_46862256) i totally agree ;-)

Comment: I proposed that because `argmax` would be faster than `where`. So, that requirement would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is efficient but

```
[int(np.isin(A, B[x]).nonzero()[0]) for x in range(len(B))]
```

seems to fit the bill. If uniqueness is not guaranteed then the `int()` part can be removed

Comment: Truthfully, I thought of this myself, but I wanted something a little less... loopy.

Answer (score 0):

If `m=A.size` and `n=B.size` the where approach is `O(mn)` . You can stay in `O((m+n)log(m+n))` by carefully sort `in1d` output (with unique values here):

```
A= np.unique(np.random.randint(0,100000,100000))
np.random.shuffle(A)
B=np.unique(np.random.randint(0,10000,10000))
np.random.shuffle(B)

def find(A,B):
    pos=np.in1d(A,B).nonzero()[0]
    return pos[A[pos].argsort()][B.argsort().argsort()]

In [5]: np.allclose(np.where(np.equal.outer(B,A))[1],find(A,B))
Out[5]: True

In [6]: %time np.where(np.equal.outer(B,A))[1]
Wall time: 3.98 s
Out[6]: array([88220, 13472, 12482, ...,  9795, 39524,  5727], dtype=int64)

In [7]: %timeit find(A,B)
22.6 ms ± 366 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```